# Qiskit: Get gates from circuit object

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, programming

Is there a way in Qiskit to take a circuit object and return a list of tuples where each tuple consists of a gate and the qubit(s) they act on? The list obeys some partial order since the gate order cannot be swapped unless they commute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inspect the QuantumCircuit.data structure:

https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html

For example, here is a loop that prints the name, qubits and any other parameters for all the gates in a circuit.

```
for gate in qc.data:
    print('\ngate name:', gate[0].name)
    print('qubit(s) acted on:', gate[1])
    print('other paramters (such as angles):', gate[0].params)
```